# Free VPN soft/service to connect two computers over internet behind NAT

Tags: windows, mac, vpn, nat

I have two computers (home and work) that I want connect to VPN. Both computers are behind NAT. I have no access to network configuration so configuring VPN server on router is not possible. Is there free service or software that know's how to do that? I use Windows at work and Mac at home.

I know that Hamachi could do that but its quite expensive.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of logmein hamachi is not centrally managed, but the price is right

https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx

Also, the paid version is only $29 per year:
https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/purchase.aspx

Review here : http://www.pcworld.com/article/258926/logmein_hamachi_gives_small_businesses_most_of_the_vpn_they_need_for_free.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a VPN server that uses UDP, for example [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/), you can use UDP hole punching to get through any NAT firewalls to create a connection between the two machines. Have a look at [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/) for an implementation of it, however it only runs on Linux or via Cygwin, so you may need to create your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

While not technically a VPN, TeamViewer is an option (free for personal use): http://www.teamviewer.com also http://crossloop.com both are very easy to setup and have excellent performance. I use Amahi's implementation of OpenVPN which is very easy to setup (also free). I have it running on a very skinny virtual machine: http://www.amahi.org/how-it-works it can also run on a Plug computer...